# How could I optimize my code to cut down on the cycles it takes to run it?

Tags: optimization, assembly, mips, cycle, division

I am a newcomer to assembly language in MIPS but I have prior experience in JAVA. I have the following block of code and was wondering how I could make it significantly faster. As you can see, this code takes a total of 45 cycles to run. You will notice that the div instruction is a big portion of the total. Maybe I could add something else in the code in place of div to optimize the code and cut down on cycles?

The code:

```
 li   $t0, -32 ----------------------2 cycles
 lw   $t2, 0($s1)--------------------1 cycle
 div  $t2, $t2, $t0------------------41 cycles
 sw   $t2, 0($s1)--------------------1 cycle
         total cycles----------------45 cycles
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you could explain the code that would help too, like what exactly do you want it to do.

Comment: You want us to optimize _four opcodes_?  Most likely, we won't be able to.

Comment: This is MIPS for `s1 /= -32;` ?  That could be replaced with `s1=(~s1-1)>>5` I think

Comment: Jesus, this is all that was given as an assignment. "Rewrite the code to make it significantly faster".

Comment: Mooing, could you explain with a little more detail what you mean? This is only the second week of me programming in MIPS assembly.

Comment: @Zoran: it's not a MIPS-specific concept. He was just using the fact that `$s1 / -32 == -$s1 / 32`. So to get rid of the division you negate `$s1` (e.g. subtract it from `$zero`), and then do an arithmetic shift of the result 5 bits to the right (a right shift by `n` bits is the same as dividing by `2^n`).

Comment: Thank you all very much for your responses. I have successfully run the program! :)